# Share This API Facebook Share Image not showing

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-sharer, sharethis

I have the trio button social media share using Share This API. Everything is ok. They are all sharing right contents. But except for the facebook share image, it cannot be registered as part of the og properties. No image is shown when the facebook popup share shows up. Can someone help please? Thanks in advance!

I actually just followed the template given by client and I dont want to change API/plugin as much as possible. And I cant find any documentation of this kind of service in the API's site http://developer.sharethis.com/.

This is the code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/sharethis.js#publisher=71dfd17f-04ad-4bd7-acfc-7a47e609cc6f&amp;type=website&amp;post_services=email%2Cfacebook%2Ctwitter&amp;button=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var BASE_URL = "http://mydemosite.com/";
         var shared_object1 = SHARETHIS.addEntry({
             title:"My Site | This is showing in fb debugger",
             url: BASE_URL,
             summary:'My summary. This is showing in fb debugger.',
             content:'My Content. This is showing in fb debugger.',
             image: BASE_URL + 'share.png'
         });
         console.log(BASE_URL + 'share.png'); //This returns exactly the url of the image
         shared_object1.attachChicklet("email", document.getElementById("share_email"));
         shared_object1.attachChicklet("facebook", document.getElementById("share_fb"));
         shared_object1.attachChicklet("twitter", document.getElementById("share_twitter"));
    </script>
```

I also checked in facebook's debugger. No image was listed under og: properties.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

It now worked when I hardcoded also in my `<head>` tag:

`<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $base_url; ?>share.png"/>`